# Ctrl-space function on roo shell unable to work on mac osx despite changing shortcut keys

Tags: eclipse, osx-snow-leopard, spring-roo

I'm on mac osx snow leopard running eclipse 3.7 with sts 2.7.2 roo 1.1.5 plugin. Under roo shell, pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will trigger spotlight so I disabled spotlight shortcut, but still roo content assist doesn't show up. Then I changed content assist shortcut for eclipse to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem continues, please file a bug in the STS Issue Tracker.

However, you can still use the Roo console from the operating system shell. In there, by default, the content assist for Roo shell works with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

I have stock sts 2.7.1 running on OSX 10.6, and default shortcut for assist is `CTRL+Space` (not `CMD+Space`)